# How can I open/close Windows Store without the Task Bar in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, windows-store-app

How can I get **Windows Store** app to open or close when the **Windows 10** taskbar is hidden or killed.

When this is the case (taskbar hidden), I am unable to find a way to allow an account to open the **Windows Store** app, nor am I able to close the opened app while this is the case.

**Note:** We push and enforce polices to client workstations making the taskbar hidden for user access restrictions to other apps except what we allow.

I'm willing to test any solution anyone could come up with including but not limited to: C# code, registry settings, etc.

Comment: If you allow the windows store app, is it also required to allow any programs a user can install through the store app?

Comment: No..    Note: I am facilitating the user the allowed store app through our windows application.

Comment: Hi Magically Delicious, Your C# code works when taskbar is not killed/hidden. but when its killed/hidden, it doesn't work..    I am killing the taskbar using C# code Or you can goto taskbar and find process "explorer.exe" (Windows Explorer) and click "end task".

Comment: (correction)--> Or you can goto TASK MANAGER* and find process "explorer.exe" (Windows Explorer) and click "end task".

Comment: Scenario is: When our XYZ Windows application(form covering complete screen) runs, I want to restrict the user from accessing all applications and windows settings, except some applications which we allow.
In order to restrict all application, I was trying to kill explorer, which inturns kills taskbar. But when i try to open ABC application which i want to allow user,  using c# code (Process.Start()), having taskbar hidden, I am not able to open. Do you have any idea how to restrict user navigating and accessing all application from taskbar and windows start button.

Answer (score 1):

> **How can I open/close windows store app, while having task bar killed in Windows 10**

One way to do this is by simply creating a desktop shortcut pointing to `ms-windows-store:` and then you'd just double-click the shortcut icon to launch it when the task bar isn't available.

1. Right-click on the desktop wallpaper
2. Select **New**
3. Select **Shortcut**
4. In the *location item* field, type in `ms-windows-store:`
5. Press <kbd>`Next`</kbd>
6. In the *shortcut name* field type in a name for the icon e.g. `Store`
7. Press <kbd>`Finish`</kbd>
8. Click on the desktop icon to launch the **Store** App
9. Press the `X` button in the upper right hand side of the **Store** app to close it

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

---

### Further Resources

- [Windows 10 Shell Commands](http://windowsreport.com/shell-commands-windows-10/)

Comment: Also available with Run (Win+R)

Comment: When taskbar is hidden, we cannot even access desktop.    Also Please Note: I am trying to open storeapp using Process.Start("..\AppxLauncher.exe", AppUserModelId).. Its allowing to open app when taskbar not hidden. but taskbar is hidden, this C# code of Process.Start() is not working.. Do you have any idea about this.